# I'm looking for books/ebooks about convex functions inequalities

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book with a nice didactics and a lot of theorems, especially Giroux's one which states that the extremes of a multivariable function, convex in any variable, has extremes on the limits of the domain.

Comment: Take a look: http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_3.pdf

Comment: ty, but this is not exactly what I want, I'm looking for books who talk about inequalities on a more math-olympic context

Comment: Guess u need sth more basic. What of https://www.math.ualberta.ca/pi/issue4/page20-24.pdf?

Comment: I already read that one :P